# difference of two columns fetched in select query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have fetched two columns `checkin_date` and `booking_time` as follows. How can i get difference of two columns thus created?

```
SELECT CAST(CONCAT(MID(Checkin,7,4) , '-' 
  , MID(Checkin,1,2)  , '-' 
  , MID(Checkin,4,2))
 AS DATETIME) as Checkin_Date,

 CAST(CONCAT(MID(Book_Time,7,4) , '-' 
  , MID(Book_Time,1,2)  , '-' 
  , MID(Book_Time,4,2))
 AS DATETIME) as Booking_Date

FROM rl_transactional.mydb
```

I tried doing `Checkin_Date - Booking_Date` before the `FROM rl_transactional.mydb` but i got error

> Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'Checkin_Date - Booking_Date   FROM rl_transactional.mydb' at line 16

**Edit**: Based on suggestion, i used below query

```
SELECT CAST(CONCAT(MID(Checkin,7,4) , '-' 
  , MID(Checkin,1,2)  , '-' 
  , MID(Checkin,4,2))
 AS DATETIME) as Checkin_Date, 

CAST(CONCAT(MID(CheckOut,7,4) , '-' 
  , MID(CheckOut,1,2)  , '-' 
  , MID(CheckOut,4,2))
 AS DATETIME) as CheckOut_Date,

 CAST(CONCAT(MID(Book_Time,7,4) , '-' 
  , MID(Book_Time,1,2)  , '-' 
  , MID(Book_Time,4,2))
 AS DATETIME) as Booking_Date,

Checkin_Date - Booking_Date
from (
    SELECT CAST(CONCAT(MID(Checkin,7,4) , '-' 
      , MID(Checkin,1,2)  , '-' 
      , MID(Checkin,4,2))
     AS DATETIME) as Checkin_Date,
     CAST(CONCAT(MID(Book_Time,7,4) , '-' 
      , MID(Book_Time,1,2)  , '-' 
      , MID(Book_Time,4,2))
     AS DATETIME) as Booking_Date
    FROM rl_transactional.mydb
) c,
FROM rl_transactional.mydb
```

I am getting below error

> Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
>   syntax to use near 'Checkin_Date - Booking_Date from (     SELECT
>   CAST(CONCAT(MID(Checkin,7,4) , '-'' at line 1

Comment: Did you put a comma before `Checkin_Date`? However, you should run DATEDIFF against Checkin and Book_Time. Possibly you'll need to cast those as dates, as well.

Comment: @JaydipJ Editing a messy question is usually a nice thing to do, but in this case there may have a typographical error which you could inadvertently correct :-)

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Thanks, I will take care of this note :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to run the following query:

```
SELECT 
     c.Checkin_Date, 
     c.CheckOut_Date
     c.Booking_Date,
     c.Checkin_Date - c.Booking_Date
from (
    SELECT CAST(CONCAT(MID(Checkin,7,4) , '-' 
      , MID(Checkin,1,2)  , '-' 
      , MID(Checkin,4,2))
     AS DATETIME) as Checkin_Date,
     CAST(CONCAT(MID(Book_Time,7,4) , '-' 
      , MID(Book_Time,1,2)  , '-' 
      , MID(Book_Time,4,2))
     AS DATETIME) as Booking_Date,
     CAST(CONCAT(MID(CheckOut,7,4) , '-' 
      , MID(CheckOut,1,2)  , '-' 
      , MID(CheckOut,4,2))
     AS DATETIME) as CheckOut_Date
    FROM rl_transactional.mydb
) c;
```

Comment: my goal is to fetch all 3 columns. How can i get Checkin_Date and Booking_Date along with the difference column?

Comment: @Enthusiast, just select them as well into parent query

Comment: i tried doing that and it gives me new error. i have edited the post with new code and error message.

Comment: No solution at sight

Answer (score 1):

if you would like to use the aliases you should incapsulate the query:

```
select Checkin_Date - Booking_Date from (
    SELECT CAST(CONCAT(MID(Checkin,7,4) , '-'
      , MID(Checkin,1,2)  , '-' 
      , MID(Checkin,4,2))
     AS DATETIME) as Checkin_Date,
     CAST(CONCAT(MID(Book_Time,7,4) , '-' 
      ,MID(Book_Time,1,2)  , '-' 
      , MID(Book_Time,4,2))
     AS DATETIME) as Booking_Date
    FROM rl_transactional.mydb )
```

**Edit**

you can't re-use an alias in the query:

try this one instead:

```
SELECT 

 Checkin_Date, 

CAST(CONCAT(MID(CheckOut,7,4) , '-' 
  , MID(CheckOut,1,2)  , '-' 
  , MID(CheckOut,4,2))
 AS DATETIME) as CheckOut_Date,

Booking_Date,

Checkin_Date - Booking_Date as Diff

from (
    SELECT CAST(CONCAT(MID(Checkin,7,4) , '-' 
      , MID(Checkin,1,2)  , '-' 
      , MID(Checkin,4,2))
     AS DATETIME) as Checkin_Date,
     CAST(CONCAT(MID(Book_Time,7,4) , '-' 
      , MID(Book_Time,1,2)  , '-' 
      , MID(Book_Time,4,2))
     AS DATETIME) as Booking_Date,
     CheckOut
    FROM rl_transactional.mydb
) c
```

Comment: i did some manipulation and ended up with a new error. Can you please help on this?